# Using the JMS session from reading a message to create a new one

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a message listener (using ActiveMQ) that implements SessionAwareMessageListener. When the onMessage(Message,Session) method is called, I parse the message and pass off its handling to a processor, along with the session for performing rollback/commit.

I need to create a new message, for placing onto an external queue. Is it ok for me to use that existing session to create the message (which I'm doing currently), or should I in fact be creating a new session, with which to create it? I'm a little hazy on exactly how JMS sessions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions share a Connection which is usually one TCP connection. Different Connections can be to different servers or use different TCP connections.

A session is single threaded. This means the messages you receive or send in the session will be in a predictable order. If you send two messages on two different sessions they can arrive in any order. (Some times this is preferable)

In the simplest use case, you will have one connection with one session.

Comment: If, after I've placed the newly created message onto the new queue and I commit my current session (as I've successfully picked up from a queue, processed the message, and then placed a new one on a new queue), then will that new message remain on the second queue for retrieval? Apologies if I'm showing my ignorance now!

Comment: We are currently picking up a message and then either rolling back the session if something goes wrong - so that the message goes back onto the queue for reprocessing later - or it's processed and put onto a new queue (be that DLQ or the proper result queue) and then committed. Is this wrong?

Comment: The message remains in the queue until it has been processed. Only the listener of that message can do that.